# How to change materialize css sidenav breakpoint

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, materialize

I use materialize's sidenav as my primary navbar, and I need to activate a top navbar on small formats, directly when the sidenav disappears, but it disappears on width **993px** which is the default value, and I need to be able to make the sidenav go lower than that, for example down to 900px.

How can I do this ?

This is my reduced navbar code :

```
<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav sidenav-fixed">
    <li>
        <a href="/" id="logo-lg"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Am I clear enough ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't get any answer here, so I finally figured it out myself.

I analyzed the css properties through the browser inspector when I get to the breakpoint (993px width), and this appears :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
.sidenav.sidenav-fixed {
     -webkit-transform: translate(-105%);
      transform: translate(-105%);
  }
```

So the answer to my question is just to rewrite the media query as you want, I did this in my case :

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .sidenav.sidenav-fixed {
         -webkit-transform: none !important;
          transform: none !important;
      }
```